# Open devtools in a separate window in atom by default

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, atom-editor

What should I do in order to open an atom's devtools in a separate window by default rather than in a dock to right/bottom mode?

Comment: Click devtools settings icon, then "dock side": float?

Comment: @wOxxOm, I don't want to each time to click on settings icon and after that to choose a show in a separate window option. I wish to just press (ctrl + shift + I) and see devtools in a separate window right at the bat.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Unfortunately Atom remembers its state only during working session.

Comment: I've restarted Atom and it still remembered the state here. Consider submitting a bug report or feature request on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electron (which Atom is based on) [should indeed remember the last mode the dev tools were opened in](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsopendevtoolsoptions):

> **`contents.openDevTools([options])`**
>
> - `options` Object (optional)
>
>   - `mode` String - Opens the devtools with specified dock state ... **Defaults to last used dock state.**

However, you can also customize this behavior if you want. By default, `cmd-option-i` (or on Windows and Linux, `ctrl-shift-i`) is bound to the Atom command `window:toggle-dev-tools`, which just calls `toggleDevTools()` on the window.

To change this behavior, you can simply overwrite that command with a new one. In your `init.coffee` (open it using `Application: Open Your Init Script` from the command palette), add the following code:

```coffeescript
atom.commands.add 'atom-workspace', 'window:toggle-dev-tools', (event) =>
  event.stopPropagation()
  BrowserWindow = require('electron').remote.BrowserWindow
  win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
  if win.isDevToolsOpened()
    win.closeDevTools()
  else
    win.openDevTools(mode: 'undocked')
```

Here, we call `stopPropagation` on the event to ensure the original handler isn't called, then simply ensure that we call `openDevTools` with `mode: unlocked` every time.

Comment: Should it be `win.openDevTools({mode: 'undocked'})` instead or `win.openDevTools(mode: 'undocked')`?

Comment: This is CoffeeScript, the default format for Atom's init script (at least at the time of this writing). Either will work.